# Enter user/pass dialog for acrobat app install: no text visible, can't type into text boxes / press buttons (pic)

Tags: macos, install, adobe

[image: No text visible, can't enter user/pass or hit 'cancel' or 'ok']

Has anyone ever seen this? I wish I could describe it better, but I hoped the picture could do the talking.

This is on a clients computer, running Mavericks, and as you can see trying to install Acrobat.

This dialog box pops up, which would normally ask you to enter your username and password, but instead no text is visible, and you can't enter text or click any buttons.

Comment: Oh adobe, your installers are legend... I'll see if I can dig up a blog post on the troubles excellent sys admin are reporting with the current batch of installers from Adobe and answer. I have strong suspicions it's the installer but don't want to answer prematurely. Hopefully this comment helps you narrow your search for a cause.

Answer (score 1):

We've experienced one of these empty dialog / password request buttons. It appears when installing any types of software it seems (such as Vectorworks for example),

If you type in your normal password (the text won't show up), it will go away.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This did not provide an answer to the question and I've removed the extra request for clarification from your answer to leave the workaround. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient reputation.